# Where can I find a good guide to writing C Collections?

Tags: c

I remember having read a very good guide to writing collections. By that I mean, it described using macros to generate types with type parameters, kind of like C++ templates. I'm not sure if it was written by Rusty Russell, but it was someone I recognized. It was posted on hackernews or proggit... I wanted to write a new C library and has searched google for the past 30 min for this guide to no avail. Anybody remember?

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup maybe. I like his book about C++

Comment: This isn't about C++.. it was using straight C macros.

Comment: Search the web for implementations of generic.h.  I'm not 100% sure it is pure C, but it was used as the basis for the early Rogue Wave H++ Collection classes.  IIRC it was entirely implemented in the headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This guide fits your description:

- [Collections in C](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2010/11/24/collections-in-c/) by Armin Ronacher.

Answer (score 3):

One example would be [`queue(3)`](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=queue&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE&format=html), see [`queue.h`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sys/queue.h).

Comment: Helpful, but not quite what I'm looking for.